# How Can I List Infinite Nested Categories on Asp.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nested-lists

I want to make nested categories.. Like;

```
Category 1
   Sub Category 1.1
      Sub Category 1.1.1
         ..
            Sub Category 1.1.1.1.1.1.1.1
Category 2
   Sub Category 2.1
   Sub Category 2.2
      Sub Categry 2.2.1
Category 3
```

My database shcema;

[image]

My ViewModel;

```
public class CategoriesViewModel
    {
        public CategoriesViewModel()
        {
            AltGroup = new List<CategoriesViewModel>();
        }

        public int CategoryID { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }    
        public List<CategoriesViewModel> SubCategories{ get; set; }
    }
```

My function;

```
private List<CategoriesViewModel> GenerateSub(List<Categories> categories)
        {
            List<CategoriesViewModel> categories= new List<CategoriesViewModel>();

            foreach (var child in categories)
            {
                var subCategories = GenerateChildren(child.Categories1.ToList());
                subCategories.Add(new CategoriesViewModel{ CategoryName = child.RoleGroupAdi, SubCategories= subCategories });
            }

            return subCategories;
        }
```

My controller file;

```
private DbEntities db = new DbEntities();
public ActionResult KullaniciYetkiGuncelle(int id = 0)
        {
            ViewModel vm = new ViewModdel();
            vm.categories = GenerateSub(db.Categories.ToList());
            return View(vm);
        }
```

My view (I have to change it I know);

```
@foreach (var item in Model.categories)
{
    @item.CategoryName
    <br />
    foreach (var item2 in item.SubCategories)
    {
        @item2.CategoryName
        <br />
        foreach (var item3 in item2.SubCategories)
        {
            @item3.CategoryName
            <br />
        }
    }
}
```

And result; FALSE LISTING

```
Sub Category 1.1
Category 1
   Sub Category 1.1
   Sub Category 1.2
      Sub Category 1.2.1
      Sub Category 1.2.2
      Sub Category 1.2.3
Sub Category 1.2
   Sub Category 1.2.1
   Sub Category 1.2.2
   Sub Category 1.2.3
Sub Category 1.2.1
Sub Category 1.2.2
Sub Category 1.2.3
```

But it must be; TRUE LISTING

```
Category 1
   Sub Category 1.1
   Sub Category 1.2
      Sub Category 1.2.1
      Sub Category 1.2.2
      Sub Category 1.2.3
```

I make mistake but I cant find and I don't have any idea about View.

Comment: What is the problem, are you worried about space or speed? If so, you don't have to extract all levels at one. You could use the same 'paging' logic used in browsing long tables.

Comment: Which control you are using to display these records?

Comment: Sorry guys, I change somethings on my question.. Check it again pls..

Comment: How you get `List<Categories>` in `GenerateSub`?

Comment: with this "private List<CategoriesViewModel> GenerateSub(List<Categories> categories)
        {"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself:

When I add `.Where(x => x.ParentCategoryID == null)`, it returns the right list.

According to that, the controller becomes:

```
private DbEntities db = new DbEntities();
public ActionResult KullaniciYetkiGuncelle(int id = 0)
{
     var vm = new ViewModdel();
     vm.categories = GenerateSub(db.Categories.Where(x=>x.ParentCategoryID == null).ToList());
     return View(vm);
}
```

For View;
Check the [checked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19152445/how-can-i-list-infinite-nested-categories-on-asp-net-mvc#19154532)..

Answer (score 2):

You need to make it a function, and call it recursively:

```
@helper PrintCategories(dynamic categories)
{
    foreach (var item in categories)
    {
        @item.CategoryName
        <br />
        var subCategories = item.SubCategories;
        if (subCategories != null && subCategories.Count > 0)
        {
            PrintCategories(subCategories);
        }
    }
}


@PrintCategories(Model.categories)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but it is onyl for view.. I changed your answer; I added controller.. Because First time I have to send only top parent category..

Comment: I didn't quite understand you edit. If you want a single "root" category, just exchange "categories" which "rootCategory", and sew it together. I understood your question as asking how to display this in the view.

Comment: I added this titles to my question; "FALSE LISTING" and "TRUE LISTING".. If you check the question again, you can understand.. When I dont add ".Where(x=>x.ParentCategoryID == null)" this codes it returns FALSE LISTING..